# Induction Motor Modelica

Tags: modelica

I have to made an Induction Motor Model by myself and my first step was to just replicate an already existing example i.e. `Electrical.Machines.Examples.AsynchronousInductionMachines.AIMC_DOL`. Now I have replicated it but I can't parameterize the `AIM_SquirrelCage` because I can't set all the default values in it. Please see attachments. And help thanks.

```
Errors: 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Symbolic    04:26:49        0:0-0:0    Too few equations, underdetermined system. The model has 485 equation(s) and 488 variable(s) 
Translation    04:26:49        0:0-0:0    Parameter aimc.statorCore.coreParameters.wRef has neither value nor start value, and is fixed during initialization (fixed=true) 
Translation    04:26:49        0:0-0:0    Parameter aimc.strayLoad.strayLoadParameters.wRef has neither value nor start value, and is fixed during initialization (fixed=true) 
Translation    04:26:49        0:0-0:0    Parameter aimc.friction.frictionParameters.wRef has neither value nor start value, and is fixed during initialization (fixed=true) 
Translation    04:26:49    D:/SF/OpenModelica1.9.0/lib/omlibrary/Modelica 3.2.1/Electrical/Machines.mo    12984:7-12987:74    Modification or redeclaration of protected elements is not allowed. 
    Element: aimc.internalThermalPort, modification: redeclare final .Modelica.Electrical.Machines.Interfaces.InductionMachines.ThermalPortAIMC internalThermalPort. 
Translation    04:26:49        0:0-0:0    Parameter aimc.friction.frictionParameters.wRef has neither value nor start value, and is fixed during initialization (fixed=true) 
Translation    04:26:49        0:0-0:0    Parameter wRef has neither value nor start value, and is fixed during initialization (fixed=true) 
Translation    04:26:49        0:0-0:0    Parameter aimc.statorCore.coreParameters.VRef has neither value nor start value, and is fixed during initialization (fixed=true)
```

Comment: I assume that Modelica is an electrical/physics modeling/simulation package of some sort.  (Google suggests similar to Simulink.)  There are a few folks around here who use it (based on a search of prior questions) but a lot of folks have no idea what it is and thus consider your question too vague.  Your question is a bit light on input data, regardless.

Comment: I agree that your question is a bit light on input data, in order to help you we need at least the modelica code of your model. Which modelica-based simulation tool are you using? Which version of the Modelica Standard Library? These errors refers to the check of whiich model (AIM_SquirrelCage, or whole InductionMachine)?